# Backand not connecting when using react-native

Tags: react-native, backend

I have created a simple object in backand with three fields - admission_no, username and password. When trying with POST method of REST API in backand, data is getting inserted successfully. But, when I am trying with my emulator, it is not getting connected to this object. I tried many things - checking url of the object, setting the security of the object to public, checking anonymous token but none of these fixed my problem.

Am I doing anything wrong? Please check the code and help me out.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
 Text,
View,
Image,
TextInput,
ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

import Container from './Container';
import Button from './Button';
import Label from './Label';
import ImageContainer from './ImageContainer';


export default class RegisterView extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    admissionNo:'',
  }
 }

 _handleAdd = () => {
 try{
 if((this.state.email)!=="" && (this.state.password)!=="" &&   
 (this.state.admissionNo)!=="" ){
  const data = {
    admission_no: this.state.admissionNo,
    username: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
  }
  const json = JSON.stringify(data);
  let response =   
  fetch('https://api.backand.com:443/1/objects/parents', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'AnonymousToken': 'abcdef',  //actual token has been given
           'Cache-Control': 'no-cache=\"set-cookie\"',
         },
         body: json
       });

       if (response.status === 200) {
         alert('Success! You may now login');
         this.props.navigator.pop();
       }
       else  {
       alert(this.state.admissionNo);
       }

     }
     else
       {
       alert ("Cannot be empty!")
       }
  }
  catch(err){
  alert(err);
  console.log(err);
  }

}
render() {
return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
    <ImageContainer>

    <Image
              style={{width:110,height: 110, justifyContent: 'center', 
alignItems: 'center'}}
              source={require('./Logo.png')}>
              </Image>
     </ImageContainer>

<Container>
<TextInput
    placeholder="Admission No."
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({admissionNo:text})}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
       const{admissionNo}=this.state.admissionNo;
       const{onSubmitEditing}=this.props;
        if(!admissionNo) return
        onSubmitEditing(admissionNo)
        this.refs.SecondInput.focus();
      }}

    />

  <TextInput
    placeholder="Username"
    style={styles.textInputUsername}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
       const{email}=this.state.email;
       const{onSubmitEditing}=this.props;
        if(!email) return
        onSubmitEditing(email)
        this.refs.SecondInput.focus();
      }}


/>

<TextInput
    placeholder="Password"
    ref='SecondInput'
    secureTextEntry={true}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})}
    style={styles.textInputPass}

 />
</Container>

         <Container>
             <Button
                 label="Create Account"
                 styles={{button: styles.primaryButton, label: 
   styles.buttonWhiteText}}
                 onPress={this._handleAdd}
                  />
         </Container>


    </ScrollView>

);

}
}
```

Comment: It's a bit challenging to tell exactly what may be going wrong here. Are you able to confirm that the web request is making it out of your emulator? If the same call works via cURL, for example, but fails in the emulator, then it could be a network bridging issue. Do you get any errors when the request is sent from the emulator?

Comment: The same call works via cURL but not in emulator. I even used production build and installed on my phone but didn't work. I don't get any errors when the request is sent from the emulator.

Comment: At a glance, your code for hitting the Backand API looks correct. However, you appear to be using our old SDK - we launched a new one, with support for react, available at https://github.com/backand/vanilla-sdk

Is there any way you can dump the requests that are failing to a temporary file in your simulator, then provide that data? If it works via cURL, but not in the emulator, that points at a network configuration issue in the emulator, but without more info I can't really be sure what's going on.

Comment: Also, you mention you don't get any errors when the request is sent from the emulator - does that mean the call completes without error, it completes with error but the error is suppressed, or the execution thread is just not getting to the portion that sends the request?